# Powershell Help system usage

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am learning powershell, so first i am learning how to use the help system of powershell. Below is the help for command "Get-EventLog",

1. what do we mean by : Position?   named
2. Also is there any links to get more on how to use the help system
   provided    by powershell?

   Synopsis
           Gets the events in an event log, or a list of the event logs, on the local or remote computers.

   ```
      Syntax   Get-EventLog [-LogName] <String> [[-InstanceId] <Int64[]>] [-After <DateTime>] [-AsBaseObject <SwitchParameter>] [-Before <DateTime>] [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-EntryType <String[]>] [-Index <Int32[]>] [-Message <String>] [-Newest <Int32>] [-Source <String[]>] [-UserName <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

   Get-EventLog [-AsString <SwitchParameter>] [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-List <SwitchParameter>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Parameters
            -After <DateTime>
                   Gets only the events that occur after the specified date and time. Enter a DateTime object, such as the one returned by the Get-Date cmdlet.
               Required?                    false
               Position?                    named
               Default value                
               Accept pipeline input?       false
               Accept wildcard characters?  false

           -InstanceId <Int64[]>
               Gets only events with the specified instance IDs.
               Required?                    false
               Position?                    2
               Default value                
               Accept pipeline input?       false

               Accept wildcard characters?  false

           -LogName <String>
               Specifies the event log.  Enter the log name (the value of the Log property; not the LogDisplayName) of one event log. Wildcard characters are not permitted. This parameter is required.
               Required?                    true
               Position?                    1
               Default value                
               Accept pipeline input?       false
               Accept wildcard characters?  false
   ```

Comment: `Required?` is a question "Is this parameter required?" Same with `Position?` "What is the position of this parameter?" `named` means you have to name the parameter for it to exist.

Answer (score 3):

For #1, you need to understand how positional parameters are used in PowerShell. You can refer to the following scripting guys article on that.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/04/22/the-problem-with-powershell-positional-parameters.aspx

For #2, in PowerShell v3, there is update-able help. By default, on PowerShell 3.0 systems, there is no help installed. Everything is online. You can download the help content using `Update-Help` and `Save-Help` cmdlets.

Also, `Get-Help <cmdletname> -Online` shows the online (most up-to-date) content for any cmdlet.

You can use the about topics in PowerShell to learn the concepts. These about topics can be accessed using `help about*`. You will see a huge list of topics which can be accessed using help or Get-Help. For example,

`help about_Parameters`

Once again, if you are using PowerShell 3.0, you need to update the help first to be able to see any help content.

Answer (score 1):

You can first have a look to [about_Command_Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347565.aspx)

```
get_help about_Command_Syntax
```

Then have a look at a few other abouts, if you want to add your own help to your Cmd-Lets have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344038/608772).