# Comment some lines in powershell script file Programmatically

Tags: powershell

How to comment multiple line in a powershell script Programmatically. I need to execute a powershell script which will copy some .ps files from share location & comment out some lines in those copied powershell script.

Comment: I believe you want a "conditional statement" (aka if) instead of modifying (commenting out) the source code lines..

Comment: Yes....but is there any option to comment out lines in powershell...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the content of the files and based on some criteria append a '#' in front of the lines you want to ignore, then save the content back to the files.

Answer (score 2):

In the "[How do you comment out code in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344038/608772)" you'll find different ways to comment in PowerShell

In you case you can avoid to modify you code lines inserting `<#` before the line(s) you want to comment and `#>` after.