# Possible to ignore code lines in VS Code debugger?

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to exclude lines of code when executing the debugger with <kbd>F5</kbd>?
In Visual Studio there's the **next statement** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>). For example, I have lines of code that perform a log in and I don't want that log in to occur each time I start the debugger.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I don't think their are another way than commenting out the code `#` or `<# >`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342597/how-do-you-comment-out-code-in-powershell/7344038#7344038

Comment: @Modro, I thought that would be necessary as the question is very generic. Like: Can I start the debugger whilst excluding lines 1-14 plus 33 plus 50-75.
I guess I'll have to stick to block comments then but I'll wait for other replies as well. Thanks.

Comment: i know that this is possible with Powershell Studio.

Comment: Don't know of this being supported atm, but VS Code supports step out/in so for your dev testing, you could just add a boolean Switch parameter that either does or doesn't trigger the code you want to avoid executing